# Why is a natural thing such as the menses associated with the deficiency in religion?

Tags: hadith, women, hadith-interpretation, menses

> **Sahih Bukhari Volume 001, Book 006, Hadith Number 301.** Narated By Abu Said Al-Khudri : Once Allah's Apostle went out to the Musalla (to
>   offer the prayer) o 'Id-al-Adha or Al-Fitr prayer. Then he passed by
>   the women and said, "O women! Give alms, as I have seen that the
>   majority of the dwellers of Hell-fire were you (women)." They asked,
>   "Why is it so, O Allah's Apostle ?" He replied, "You curse frequently
>   and are ungrateful to your husbands. I have not seen anyone more
>   deficient in intelligence and religion than you. A cautious sensible
>   man could be led astray by some of you." The women asked, "O Allah's
>   Apostle! What is deficient in our intelligence and religion?" He said,
>   "Is not the evidence of two women equal to the witness of one man?"
>   They replied in the affirmative. He said, "This is the deficiency in
>   her intelligence. Isn't it true that a woman can neither pray nor fast
>   during her menses?" The women replied in the affirmative. He said,
>   "This is the deficiency in her religion."

Menses is a naturally occurring thing for adult woman. If Allah prohibited certain activities for women during this time according to hadith, then why it's a deficiency in religion?

Comment: Actually, I just read a Hadith in Al-Bukhari where 'Aisha was complaining about some of the things that was said about women in early Islam. She does not directly quote the Prophet on this. And it may simply be that she was complaining how Islamic rulings were already being misinterpreted even at that early stage.

Answer (score 2):

The way the hadith explains it is already rather clear, but I'll spell it out because I'm sick of seeing it quoted by anti-Islam sites who insist on twisting words from their right places:

1. Praying, fasting and giving charity are all part of the religion.
2. Women don't pray and fast during their menses.
3. Therefore there is a shortage in their religion.
4. Giving charity can make up for this shortcoming.

It has nothing to do with the menses itself except for the fact that that's the reason that women don't pray or fast.

Comment: One could add that during their menses women are not allowed to pray and fast, which means they will miss the rewards related to these acts of worship, but they can compensate it by giving charity.

Comment: To help me understand: If someone is involved in an accident that he did not cause and ends up in a coma, is that person expected to make up for the stuff he missed as well even though it wasn't his fault and entirely out of his control?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen, prayers need not be made up for, but fasting needs to expiated for ... same as a woman in menses. If one dies without being able to make up or expiate for days not fasted, it becomes the responsibility of one's guardian to do so (see [Sahih al-Bukhari 30/59](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/59)).

Answer (score 0):

Women wont lose anything when they are in menses. Something like pray or fast are replaceable by itself. You can fast later its so simple. 
I saw a hadith in al-kafi, third book page 113, but I translate it with google translate sorry far that:

"The Prophet of God looked up to the sky and smiled, asked him the cause, and said: "I was surprised by two angels who descended from heaven to earth and went to the believer in the mosques in which they prayed to go to practice him." They did not find him at his prayer. So they went to heaven and said: "Our Lord, we went to the servant of the believer in Mordecai to write his deeds, but We found him in your trap." Then he said: "For my servant, as long as he is in my trap, write like good and reward done at the time of his health." Because it is upon me that when I take out the health from him, I will give the work done at his health."

Comment: This answer could benefit from some evidences and sources of your quotation ...